# Dictionary: Syllable-hyphenation interpuncts (dots) missing

Tags: mac, macos, dictionary

This is regarding the Dictionary app (New Oxford American Dictionary) that comes with Mac OS X. I currently have version 2.2.1 (156) in Mavericks (10.9.1).

In previous versions (Mountain Lion, Snow Leopard, Tiger…), words were shown with interpunctual dots between hyphenate-able syllables—and now they're gone.

These were very useful for copyediting…is there any way (keyboard shortcut, Terminal command) to bring them back? Thanks!

Tiger Dictionary example entry:

[image: Tiger Dictionary example entry]

Mavericks Dictionary example entry:

[image: Mavericks Dictionary example entry]

Comment: I don't know of any way to change the way a dictionary displays things, but the Japanese-English dictionary still has the older dots I think.

Answer (score 2):

You can install the old dictionary from your old OS X install disk.

Here's what I did with my Snow Leopard disk on my Mavericks installation:

- Quit Dictionary
- Turn ON hidden file visibility in Finder by typing this into Terminal:

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles Yes
  ```
- Rename **/Library/Dictionaries/New Oxford American Dictionary.dictionary** to something like  **New Oxford American Dictionary-orig.dictionary**, since you'll be putting the older OS X version of this dictionary here.
- Grab the application Pacifist from http://www.charlessoft.com and run it
- Pop in your old OS X Install disk to your DVD Drive
- Find the dictionary package.  I found mine here:

  ```
  /Volumes/Mac OS X Install DVD/System/Installation/Packages/OxfordDictionaries.pkg
  ```
- drag this package into Pacifist
- Within Pacifist, find your dictionary folder named **New Oxford American Dictionary.dictionary**
- Drag this folder into /Library/Dictionaries
- Start up Dictionary
- Optional: Go into preferences and enable/disable the dictionaries you want.  The just-copied dictionary is probably already enabled, since it has the same name as the original dictionary.  But you can also enable the original dictionary so that both are active.
- You can turn off HIDDEN FILE view by typing into Terminal:

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles No
  ```

Now, I have the syllables displayed on Mavericks!

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been removed from the recent dictionaries in OS X, and there does not appear to be an option to re-enable it.

The dots are still present in the Japanese-English dictionary (Dictionary → Preferences):

[image]

You can provide feedback to Apple regarding this at the following page:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html

Answer (score 0):

Just try to select in the Preferences of Dictionary app (v.2.2.1 in OS X 10.8.5) unselected "New Oxford American Dictionary" option. Hyphenation dots will show to you after this, if in Dictionary you'll search for words with "All" tab or "English (USA)" tab for results.

Comment: Mac OS X version 8.5 is Mountain Lion. This issue only exists in post–Mountain Lion versions (Mavericks, Yosemite).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in OS X Yosemite, but I found a quick workaround for finding out where the syllables break. Open Dictionary, go to the Dictionary menu, select Preferences and turn on the Korean-English source. I can't read the descriptions but at least it has the "dot" breaks.